# Is "chop down" OK here?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idiomatic-language

A crazy man with an ax runs over to a gigantic Christmas tree at a city square and starts swinging at it.

> Someone: Hey! Stop him! He's trying to **chop down** the tree!

What would you native speakers say here? Is "chop down" OK?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  You should be able to find the phrasal verb "chop down" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "chop down" can be used in your scenario.

From, [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chop-sth-down), "chop down" is a phrasal verb, meaning:

> to cut through something to make it fall down:
> *Most of the diseased trees were chopped down last year.*

From [the National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/travel/2020/12/christmas-tree-customs/):

> Every December, people in regions around the world head to the nearest forest, ***chop down*** a tree, drag it into their homes, adorn it with lights, baubles, and tinsel—then unceremoniously drag it to the curb in January.

> *(emphasis mine)*

Alternatively, you can also use "cut down", however "chop down" signifies a more extreme action which fits in your proposed sentence.